# Unexpected Token ( in function

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error:

> Error: Line 1: Unexpected token (

in this code:

```
onInit: function (bus) {
      // Message bus created and ready to be used,
                            window.bus = bus;
                 } 

 };
```

I cant figure out why I am getting this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add you complete code, Is this `onInit:` inside an object i.e. is it an object key (property)? If no, then it is not a correct syntax if you are trying to declare it as a variable.

Comment: Based on the question title, it just seems like a syntax error. Can you post entire code?

Answer (score 1):

What you've posted is the syntax for the ***contents*** of an **[Object Literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/)**, but not the outer "shell" of that syntax, so yes, you have an unexpected bit of code as far as the JavaScript runtime is concerned:

```js
onInit: function (bus) {
      // Message bus created and ready to be used,
                            window.bus = bus;
                 } 
};
```

What you need is to place the "shell" of the object literal around that code:

```js
let someObj = {
  onInit: function (bus) {
  // Message bus created and ready to be used,
    window.bus = bus;
  } 
};

// Now, you can use your object:
someObj.onInit("TEST");
console.log(window.bus);
```

By the way, creating new properties on the Global `window` object is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
var onInit = function (bus) {
  window.bus = bus;
};
```

Comment: You should ask for clarification in comments before guessing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the opening bracket `{` if this was suppose to be a function inside an object...

```
{
  onInit: function (bus) {
    // Message bus created and ready to be used,
    window.bus = bus;
  } 
}
```

If it's not suppose to be in an object, then one of the following should do:

```
function onInit (bus) {
  // Message bus created and ready to be used,
  window.bus = bus;
}
```

or...

```
var onInit = functtion (bus) {
  // Message bus created and ready to be used,
  window.bus = bus;
}
```

Comment: dude, yes! you are awesome. believe it or not this was in a well known company's api documentation. I just did a copy and paste over.